Server-Sent Events (SSE) wit RESTEasy exhausting Jetty's thread pool
EDIT:

Got rid of Thread.sleep() using an executor instead.
Added call to servletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true).


Question
We are trying to implement Server-Sent Events (SSE) using

RESTEasy (6.2.11.Final)
Jetty (12.0.15)

but we are having the problem that each SSE subscription consumes and holds on to a thread in Jetty's thread pool for the entire duration of the subscription.
If we use Jersey instead of RESTEasy, everything works as expected.
Is there are way to configure RESTEasy to not exhausting Jetty's thread pool?
Code implementing SSE using RESTEasy
A resource class to handle SSE subscriptions and push events to a subscriber every second:
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context;
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.OutboundSseEvent;
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.Sse;
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink;

@Path("/events")
public class EventsResource {
    private final static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    private final static AtomicInteger channelIds = new AtomicInteger();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void subscribe(@Context SseEventSink sink, @Context Sse sse) {
          final int channelId = channelIds.getAndIncrement();
          final Runnable sendMessage = () -> {
                final OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder()
                    .name("message")
                    .data(String.class, "Hello client " + channelId + "!")
                    .build();
                sink.send(event);
          };
          executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(sendMessage, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

The resource class is added to the set of classes in our Application class:
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class RestApplication extends Application {
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(EventsResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}

Finally, we have our main class where we start Jetty with our application and a minimal thread pool of 5 threads:
import org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;
import org.example.rest.RestApplication;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(5));

    ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server);
    serverConnector.setPort(8081);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { serverConnector });

    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new HttpServletDispatcher());
    servletHolder.setInitParameter("jakarta.ws.rs.Application", RestApplication.class.getName());
    servletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
    server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);

    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
}

Exhausting Jetty's thread pool
When subscribing to SSE, we get:
% curl "http://localhost:8081/events" -H 'Accept: text/event-stream'

event: message
data: 0: Hello client 0!

event: message
data: 1: Hello client 0!

event: message
data: 2: Hello client 0!

...

If we start 2 parallel curl commands, the Jetty thread pool is exhausted and the 3rd request will hang waiting for a thread.

All your thread busy doing Thread.sleep(1000);

What would the expected behavior be? A SseBroadcaster might do what you're expecting.

@talexmovedtoCodidact I have updated the question above using your suggestion in the answer below. It seems the problem is in RESTEasy's implementation of async support. Swapping RESTEasy with Jersey makes the problem go away and we can serve multiple SSE sinks without holding on to any threads in Jetty. Any idea if we have misconfigured RESTEasy or overlooked something?
(For reasons … we cannot use Jersey.)

First you add scheduler to your class:
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

Then change your method to
  @GET
  @Produces("text/event-stream")
  public void subscribe(@Context SseEventSink sink, @Context Sse sse) throws InterruptedException {
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(()-> {
              final OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder()
                          .name("message")
                          .data(String.class, "Hello client!")
                          .build();
              sink.send(event);
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }


I know that I was simply sleeping in my simple example and that in itself will hold on to Jetty's thread. However, doing as you suggest does not solve the problem. It seems the SseEventSink is holding on to Jetty's thread as long as the SSE channel is open. So I need a way to somehow keep the underlying HTTP connection open (for use with the SseEventSink) without holding on to a thread from Jetty's thread pool. Maybe some of Jetty's async capabilities are useful.
